# How do I fix my .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So this is my .htaccess so far:

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
order deny,allow
deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName site.com
#Redirect 301 / http://www.google.com/

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

What I am trying to do is the following:

index.php?page=pagesite -> site.com/pagesite

But if I go to site.com/images it doesnt go to /images it goes to index.php?page=images

How do I fix that?

Also, is there anyway that if "pagesite" is not in /includes/pages/ it redirects to the 404?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you're trying to return images and other plain files returned directly and not by PHP:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the file exists, return it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

[This is my typical setup](http://docforge.com/wiki/Mod_rewrite#Everything_Handled_By_Index.php).

As for 404, since everything else goes to index.php, it should be returned by your PHP code.